# Magento 2 with multiple domain names

Tags: magento2, multidomain

I have Magento 2 with two store views: one with code "a" and one with code "b".

I have set up two domains **mydomain.a** and **mydomain.b**,  with public folders

**/a/public_html/**

**/b/public_html/**

now

**/a/public_html/index.php** looks like

```
<?php
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'a';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

and **/b/public_html/index.php** looks the same except that I have 'b' in the 3rd line.

in **/b/public_html/** I have set up symbolic links to all folders in **/a/public_html/** (app, bin, dev, pub,...).

the "base URL" properties for store view "a" is "**http://www.mydomain.a**" and for "b" "**http://www.mydomain.b**".

But when I go to **mysite.a** it looks fine, but when I go to **mysite.b** it redirects to **mysite.a** and language is a, not b.
And when I go to either mysite.b/admin or mysite.a/admin it starts to loop from a to b and I get "This website has a redirect loop".

Isn't this super weird? Perhaps if I have two full installations of Meganto 2 and just a common database, would this work?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this will help anybody, I use this in my index.php and works like a charm :)

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.domain-x.com':
    case 'domain-x.com':
        $params = $_SERVER; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'x'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
        break; 
    case 'www.domain-y.com':
    case 'domain-y.com':
        $params = $_SERVER; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'y'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
    break; 

    default: 
        Mage::run(); 
    break; 
}
```

Comment: what is  Mage::run(); doing?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to edit the `index.php` or `.htaccess` files. You just need to add the ENV variables to your vhosts file after you have [setup the store in the magento admin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html).

Here is an example vhosts file for apache 2. The main website is "mysite.mg" and two sub-sites "french.mysite.mg" and "german.mysite.mg":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          mysite.mg
    DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          french.mysite.mg
    DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "french"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          german.mysite.mg
    DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "german"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
</VirtualHost>
```

The `SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE` is the code that you setup when you created the website in the magento admin and `SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE` is "website" when you are using the website code. [Here is a link for reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using Magento 2, we can implement multi domain with single Magento 2 installation.  and there is no need to create separate folders like

> /a/public_html/ & /b/public_html/

You can read this docs for more clarification.
[Read More](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-run.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is super weird :) Magento allow multi domain setup web site without creating two separate installations

**Stores -> Settings -> All Stores**

Let’s look at each of three options

Web site
We need to focus on web site section of all stores. In default Magento comes with one web site (base). If you need more domains you need to create more web sites.

Websites not sharing cart, user sessions, payment gateways, shipping etc.

Store
Each website have at lease one store. Stores share cart, payment gateways etc.
Typically used in different product selections, menu structure etc.

Store View
Stores can have one or several store views. Store views typically used in layouts and lanugages

Next you need to go to

**Admin -> configuration**

Set up your domain for **Base Urls** And **Base Urls (secure)** for both web sites

Then in your index.php

Open your index.php file and replace following line.

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $server);
```

With following 4 lines of code

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

.htaccess changes
Open your root .htaccess file and add following lines

```
SetEnvIf Host .*multidomain.fc5.forge.co.nz.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host .*multidomain.fc5.forge.co.nz.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host .*australian.fc5.forge.co.nz.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=australia
SetEnvIf Host .*australian.fc5.forge.co.nz.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Go to #RewriteBase /magento/ and include following lines of code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)multidomain\.fc5\.forge\.co\.nz
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:base]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)multidomain\.fc5\.forge\.co\.nz
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)australian\.fc5\.forge\.co\.nz
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:australia]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)australian\.fc5\.forge\.co\.nz
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

Find out more from full article at
http://www.forgeonline.co.nz/magento-multistore-website-shopfront/

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your site base_url is the same for both sites.  This is stored in the database.  Each web site will redirect to this url so if they are the same in both databases or you are using the same database you could see this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is no need to create other site folder, just same website folder.
In my case, prepare multiple stores, and using MobileDetectLib on index.php to redirect to specific  URL.

VI MagentoWebSite/index.php

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.MagentoWebSite.com'){
    require_once 'MagentoWebSite/vendor/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib/Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    if($detect->isMobile()) {
        header('Location: http://m.MagentoWebSite.com/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**edit in pub/index.php**

if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='magento.local'){
    $_SERVER[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'ps';
    $_SERVER[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
}elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='francemagento.local'){
    $_SERVER[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'fr';
    $_SERVER[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
}else{
    echo "webiste is not running";
}
```